# AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_food' python

Tags: python, factory, abstract

I'm using abstract factory pattern
I have these three classes, in separated scripts

```
class Dog1:

    def speak(self):
        return "Woof!"

    def __str__(self):
        return "Dog"


from dog1 import Dog1

class DogFactory(Dog1):

    def get_pet(self):
        return Dog1()


    def get_food(self):
        return "Dog food!"



from dog_factory import DogFactory

class PetStore(DogFactory):

    def __init__(self, pet_factory=None):
        self._pet_factory=pet_factory


    def show_pet(self):


        pet_food=self._pet_factory.get_food()

        print("its food is {}".format(pet_food))
```

In my python console I write :

```
>>pet=PetStore()
>>pet.show_pet()
```

and then the error is: AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get_food'
Is there any other way of instantiating?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What do you mean "other way"?  Your `pet_factory` argument has a default of None, so that's what `_pet_factory` gets set to.  What are you expecting it to do?

Comment: The thing is, if in PetStore class I don't extend the DogFactory class but instead in console i instantiate like : >>> dog=DogFactory()
>>> pet=PetStore(dog)
>>> pet.show_pet()
it actually works:
its food is Dog food!

Comment: Even if I delete the None default value, I still keep having this error!

Comment: If that works, then why did you make PetStore a subclass of DogFactory at all?

Comment: I needed to do it that way and it would be really helpful if for me If I can find a way to make this work, without instantiating in console

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `PetStore.show_pet()` is trying to call `self._pet_factory.get_food()`, but `self._pet_factory` defaults to `None`.

Basically, your `PetStore` doesn't have an `is-a` relationship to `DogFactory`, so you are only confusing the issue by subclassing it.

What you probably want is to leave `DogFactory` out of `class PetStore`:

```
class PetStore(object):
```

and then specify the factory when you instantiate:

```
    def __init__(self, pet_factory):  # notice no default here
        self._pet_factory = pet_factory

pet = PetStore(DogFactory())
pet.show_pet()
# It's food is Dog Food!
```

Comment: if i try to call the get_pet() method instead of get_food(), I get the error  " 'NoneType' object is not callable ", any idea?